# Getting 'undeclared identifier' when using vector of type class

Tags: c++, object, vector, member, undeclared-identifier

Having trouble understanding why I'm getting an 'undeclared identifier' error when I've made sure to include the header file that has the declaration of the class I'm making a vector of.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Member.h"

class Party {
private:
    std::vector<Member> members;

public:
    Party();
    int get_party_size();
    void add_member(Member new_member);
    Member& get_member(int num);

};
```

Here's "Member.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Party.h"

class Member
{
private:
    int hp;
    bool is_stunned;
    bool is_alive;

public:
    Member();
    ~Member();
    int get_hp();
    bool get_is_stunned();
    bool get_is_alive();
    void take_damage(int amt);
    void stun();

    virtual void turn(std::vector<Party>& parties, int my_party, int my_member_number);
    virtual std::string get_class_name();

};
```

Pretty new to the language, so sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What does member.h look like?

Comment: My guess is that `Member.h` includes `Party.h` and you have a circular dependency.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good guess! :)

Comment: The way to solve your problem is to break the circular inclusion dependency. That is usually done with *forward declarations* of the classes.

Comment: @Anders Seen it way to many time before... :)

Answer (score 1):

You have circular dependency between Member and Party

Remove the line

```
virtual void turn(
  std::vector<Party>& parties, 
  int my_party, 
  int my_member_number);
```

in Member and remove the `#include "Party.h"` in Member.h

Instead think along the lines that a Party is just a collection of Members so there is no need for an individual Member to know about the container

So after input from @some-programmer-dude you could also solve it by adding a forward declaration in your Member.h instead of including the Party.h

```
class Party;

class Member { ... }
```

Comment: That function declaration that you say needs to be removed doesn't really need to be removed. That line itself doesn't depend on the full definition of the `Party` class, all it needs is a forward declaration.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I was looking at it from the design perspective, IMHO it would be better if the Member did not  have a dependency to the Party. But hey what do I know what he needs :)